# OleDB Simple CSV Import

Tags: c#, oledb

The Code below prompts the user to select a csv file, and then parses the data into the datatable based on column names. So if the first row of the CSV file shows "Col1" and the Table has a "Col1" column, all of the data in the CSV file under Col1 is put in as rows filling under the DataTables Col1.

If the column names in the CSV don't match up with anything in the DataTable however it throws an "External table is not in the expected format." error.

I want to change the system so that it uploads in a much less intelligent way. and then I'll give the user the option to assign columns manually in a WPF window.

Does anyone know how to make this just upload the raw data? Disregarding column names and just putting everything in the first column of the CSV into the first column of the DataTable?

```
try
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog().Value)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(openFileDialog1.FileName);

    string pathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=2\"";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn);

    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + "sheet1" + "$]", conn);

    myDataAdapter.Fill(displayTable);

} catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error! : " + e.Message);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Where is the alleged "SQL Database"?  All I see is some Excel OleDB related code

Comment: Don't use oledb(), but then the code becomes more complicated.  You can always take the datatable results and move to new object.

Comment: @Plutonix DataBase code is handled later. It's being parsed into a WPF datagrid first.

Comment: @jdweng I was hoping to keep the code simple. but I'll go this direction if I have to.

Comment: You can provide mappings for both tables and columns which would make it fairly simple to insert the DataTable contents to something else somewhere else.  Involving the user is the creepy part

Comment: You can always use string split to separate the data around the commas and not use oledb.